# HTML/css text in table cell not indenting

Tags: html, css, html-table

A simple question but large impact on appearance.

I want text indented from cell border and have tried  `style=text-indent: 4px` (not formatted so it displays properly here) but while the first line is indented, the lines after the `<br>` tags are not indenting.  Please help.  I need to use div because of some Javascript. Here is flawed code:

```
<td>
   <div id="navbar" style="text-indent:4px"><b>View by:</b><br>
      <a href="search.php?cat=pop">Popular</a><br>
      <a href="search.php?cat=trend">Trending</a><br>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: A table cell? Consisting of a navbar? [Don't use tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Comment: A collection of links? Separated by line breaks? [Do use list markup for your lists of links](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/)

Comment: `<b>` is not a heading element. Look to `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

Comment: You are right...I don't know css for beans, however, so am just using tables for now.  Looking forward to having someone who really knows it convert to tableless structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`text-indent` is only supposed to touch the first line. Use `margin` (or `margin-left` or `padding` or etc) if you want to adjust the entire block.

Comment: what would the syntax be for padding?

Comment: I just put in padding:4px and it worked.  It won't let me accept answer for a while but thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try adding paddding to element, that holds your text you want to indent.

```
   <td style="padding:5px;">text</td>
```